# Duplex printing not available.

Tags: printing

Epson artisan 720 unable to access duplex printing in ubuntu 16.04 (selection box grayed out). Worked OK in 14.04

Answer (score -1):

intrigued you could do duplex on an Epson; in 14.04

I had got the impression that the drivers Epson issued for linux didn't enable duplex: we have a model of the XP and whilst it does duplex in windows I understand, it won't on linux

but I see the turboprint offer duplex http://www.zedonet.com/en_p_turboprint_driver.phtml?printer=Epson_StylusArtisan725

you can get turboprint from here http://www.turboprint.info/download.html
the free version is limited; they ask for a contribution to the full version